# AVPLayer with SwiftUI for playing video

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, video, avplayer

I wanted to play AVPlayer like youtube shorts videos, I have been using the links from the youtube shorts with there videoId's, but AVPlayer is not supporting those links. is there any chance to convert those shorts id links to supportable format for AVPlayer

```
    @State var currentVideoIndex: Int
    @State var player: AVPlayer
    @State var playerList: [AVPlayer] = []
    
    let videoURLs = [
    URL(string: "https://youtube.com/shorts/-3qL9gC_FE4?si=oZjHfoWx1KrIFTO-")!,
    URL(string: "https://youtube.com/shorts/s2wfgJuexyk?si=r3LrspHMqgCzbqWw")!,
    URL(string: "https://youtube.com/shorts/c1IomVJi7Vo?si=xjdV58E3I4g95sHP")!
    ]

    VideoPlayer(player: player) {
        
    }.gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 20, coordinateSpace: .local).onEnded { gesture in
        player.volume = 0
        if gesture.translation.width < 0 {
            currentVideoIndex = (currentVideoIndex + 1)%videoURLs.count
        } else if gesture.translation.width > 0 {
            currentVideoIndex = (currentVideoIndex - 1)%videoURLs.count
        }
        setupPlayer(index: currentVideoIndex)
    })
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .onAppear {
            playerList.append(AVPlayer(url: videoURLs[0]))
            playerList.append(AVPlayer(url: videoURLs[1]))
            playerList.append(AVPlayer(url: videoURLs[2]))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you realise this is against Youtube's Terms of Service?